# General term of this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, prime-numbers, integer-partitions

I wanted to know the General term or the function to generate [this sequence I found on OEIS](http://oeis.org/A046927).
It is the number of ways to express $2n+1$ as $p+2q$; where $p$ and $q$ can be odd prime number and even semiprime not necessarily distinct.

Comment: There will not be anything nice.

Answer (score 1):

There is no formula for the general term of the sequence A046927. The [conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemoine%27s_conjecture) that the sequence consists of positive integers remains open.

Comment: Then how did they generate the sequence up to 1000 terms?

Comment: @AdwaitKumar The page to which you linked has Mathematica code for computing this sequence.